# The conjugate of a subbundle of the complexified tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Given a smooth manifold $M$ and consider the complexified tangent bundle $TM\otimes\mathbb C$. Let $HM$ be a subbundle of $TM\otimes\mathbb C$. What do we mean by $\overline {HM}$?

Comment: There is a conjugation $\bar{(\cdot)} : T_xM \otimes \mathbb C\to T_xM \otimes \mathbb C$ sending $v\otimes z$ to $v\otimes \bar z$. I suppose $\bar{HM}$ is the image of $HM$ under this map.

Comment: Is the map $\bar{( \cdot)}$ has anything to do with the complex structure $J$ on $TM\otimes C$?

Comment: Which complex structure on $TM \otimes C$?

Comment: I am not sure actually. is there any complex structure on $TM\otimes C$ since it is complex vector bundle?

Comment: I see, so it is probably this one: $J(v\otimes z) = v\otimes (iz)$?

Comment: Exactly! So is there any easy tool to check that $HM\cap\bar{HM}=\{0\}$ for example?